# HOW TO CONVERT TRIPLE TAG IN METEOR 0.7.0.1 ACCORDING TO VERSION 0.8.0

Tags: meteor

I have updated meteor application to version 0.8.0 from 0.7.0.1. Every changes tried to do but not able to figure out, how to change triple tag according to new version. Referred the following link and tried to do so but still getting error.

The link following is:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

The code of .html file is: Basically this {{{done }}} part. I tried to change according to the above link as {{> done}}. But then getting error as ""Reactive HTML attributes must either have a constant name or consist of a single {{helper}} providing a dictionary of names and values.  A template tag of type INCLUSION is not allowed here.
    ""

```
    <template name="subscribedKeyword"> 
        <div class="issue" > 
            <div class="issue-content">
                <h3>
                    {{category}} 
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input id='check' class="checktype" name="mark" type="checkbox"  value="1" {{{ done}}} />Get Notifications
                    <input type="hidden" name="mark" value="0" />
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

The corresponding .js file code is: I think that there is no need to change anything in this file. As according to the above link, changes need to be done in the html file only.

```
    Template.subscribedKeyword.done = function () {
        // alert('inside done function');
        var subscribedUsersOfThisDomain=  Subscribed.findOne(this._id);
        var subscribedPersons =  subscribedUsersOfThisDomain.categorySubscribedUsers;
        // alert('before if block in done function');
        if(subscribedPersons && subscribedPersons.length)
        {
            var j;
            var ch='';

            // alert('before loop in done function');
            for(j= 0;j< subscribedPersons.length;j++)
            {
                //alert('j '+j);
                //alert('person '+person[j].username);
                if(subscribedPersons[j].username === Meteor.user().username)
                {   
                    ch ="checked";
                    // alert('value of ch that is set'+ch);
                    break; 
                }
            }
            if(ch=== 'checked')
            {
                // alert('while returning value in if block');
                return 'checked="checked"';
            }
            else        
            {
                // alert('while returning value in else block');
                return '';
            }

        }
        else
            return '';

    };
```

Do let me know what changed need to be done. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can see is:

```
<template name="subscribedKeyword"> 
    <div class="issue" > 
        <div class="issue-content">
            <h3>
                {{category}} 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <input id='check' class="checktype" name="mark" type="checkbox"  value="1" checked={{done}} />Get Notifications
                <input type="hidden" name="mark" value="0" />
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Template.subscribedKeyword.done = function () {
    // alert('inside done function');
    var subscribedUsersOfThisDomain=  Subscribed.findOne(this._id);
    var subscribedPersons =  subscribedUsersOfThisDomain.categorySubscribedUsers;
    // alert('before if block in done function');
    if(subscribedPersons && subscribedPersons.length)
    {
        var j;
        var ch='';

        // alert('before loop in done function');
        for(j= 0;j< subscribedPersons.length;j++)
        {
            //alert('j '+j);
            //alert('person '+person[j].username);
            if(subscribedPersons[j].username === Meteor.user().username)
            {   
                ch ="checked";
                // alert('value of ch that is set'+ch);
                break; 
            }
        }
        if(ch=== 'checked')
        {
            // alert('while returning value in if block');
            return "checked";
        }
        else        
        {
            // alert('while returning value in else block');
            return null;
        }

    }
    else
        return null;

};
```

According to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected